# Position of images inside of Bar item

Tags: swift, xcode, vector, toolbar

[image: Problem with positioning of images (pdf) inside the toolbar]
There is a problem with positioning of images (pdf. Single scale). Simulator shows images of toolbar items in wrong position.
I tried to apply Image inset: top: -6 - doesn't help.
What's wrong with vector graphics? if I try to use .png - it looks correct.

[image: png image has correct position insed the toolbar item]

Also I can't apply title for toolbar items with images: there are only two options: or image | or title... Why is that?

Comment: http://imgur.com/xc1zJdo
[img]http://i.imgur.com/xc1zJdo.png[/img]
Also I don't see anything wrong with vector graphics files

Comment: Sorry. I found solution by adding transparent bounding box in vector files:
[link]http://imgur.com/qTiEtcH